# problems using a class to read a file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have to read a file using a java class with a method called llegir() and it's supposed to read one word from a sequence of characters. Inside this method there is another one called botarBlancs() and what this method does it's simply knowing when a word is finished, because it has found a blank.

Here's the whole class:

```
public class Paraula {
// Constants públiques

public static final char blanc = ' ';
public static final char fiSequencia = '.';
// Constants privades
// Llargària màxima d'una paraula
private static final int MAXIM = 20;
// ATRIBUTS
private char[] lletres;
private int llargaria; 
// atribut de classe, per simplificar les operacions de lectura
private static char lletra = ' ';
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++EXTRA
private static char[] frase = null;
private static int indice;
// INTERFICIE
// Constructor

public Paraula() {
    lletres = new char[MAXIM];
    llargaria = 0;
}
// llegir una paraula de la seqüència d'entrada

public static Paraula llegir() {
    Paraula nova = new Paraula();
    botarBlancs();
    while ((lletra != fiSequencia) && // No ha acabat la seqüència
            (lletra != blanc)) { // Hi ha prou espai
        nova.lletres[nova.llargaria++] = lletra;
        lletra = leerCarTeclado();
    }
    //System.out.println(nova.girar());
    return nova;
}

// Convertir un objecte Paraula en un String
public String toString() {
    String msg = "";
    for (int idx = 0; idx < llargaria; idx++) {
        msg += lletres[idx];
    }
    return msg;
}
// Per comparar amb une altre objecte Paraula

public boolean esIgualA(Paraula b) {
    boolean iguals = llargaria == b.llargaria;
    for (int idx = 0; (idx < llargaria) && iguals; idx++) {
        iguals = lletres[idx] == b.lletres[idx];
    }
    return iguals;
}
// Per comparar dos objectes Paraula. És un mètode de classe

public static boolean iguals(Paraula a, Paraula b) {
// Fa ús del mètode esIgualA definit abans
    return a.esIgualA(b);
}
// Per determinar si la paraula és buida

public boolean buida() {
    return llargaria == 0;
}
// Mètodes que no formen part de la interfície

// llegir el que sigui necessari fins començar la paraula
public static void botarBlancs() {
    while (lletra == blanc) {
        lletra = leerCarTeclado();
    }
}
// botar-se la resta de caràcters que puguin quedar si la
// paraula és massa llarga.

public static void botarParaula() throws Exception {
    while ((lletra != '.') && (lletra != blanc)) {
        lletra = leerCarTeclado();
    }
}
static public char leerCarTeclado() {
    char res = '.';
    if (frase != null) {
        res = frase[indice++];
    }
    return res;
}
```

What I want to do is to save one line of a file, then convert it into a char array and then I want to use this class to read it, etc.

Here's the code:

```
    public static void generador_de_cartas() throws Exception{
    Paraula pl = new Paraula();
    Paraula nRef, dRef, tipo, codigo;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("datos_clientes.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = br.readLine();
    char [] linea;
    while (line != null) {
        linea=line.toCharArray();
        linea=pl.llegir();

        line=br.readLine();

    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

When I use line=pl.llegir(), Netbeans says that Paraula cannot be converted into char[] and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Please help me, 
thanks!!

Comment: linea=pl.llegir();
linea is a character array. 
llegir returns an object of type Paraula.
You would have to write linea=pl.llegir().lletres
But I can't tell if that's what you really want to assign. Also, the line before that is redundant: what ever you assign with that line will be overwritten.

Comment: From what I can see you are using llegir in a wrong way my friend. It is a static method so you should call it directly.


Also it returns a Paraula and you are getting its value into an array of characters which can't be work at all.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the last sentence @AhmedKamal . Could you try to explain it again please?

Comment: I mean that you are trying to assign the return type of your method into a char array although it returns a different type (which is ur class Paraula)

Comment: So how can I do it to make it work using my class Paraula? @AhmedKamal